# Set / Change url for a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I want to host a single shiny app within a Docker container. At the moment the App is listening on http://127.0.0.1:7417.

Is it possible to change the url of the app to http://127.0.0.1:7417/stats/ without the use of a shiny server?

I have tried shiny.router which lead to http://127.0.0.1:7417/#!/stats/
and uiStub which lead to http://127.0.0.1:7417/?stats/

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this, but I just wanted to point out that if you flip the first letter of your last name upside down you get my name; Florian Maas.